# Как сделать проверить текущий пароль и сменить сам пароль

Tags: yii2

Всем доброй ночи, не могу ни как проверить текущий пароль, так как в таблице есть сохраненный в хеше пароль как их сравнить и заменить на новый.

```
        if ($this->validatePassword($this->current_password)) {
        $password = $this->setPassword($this->new_password);
        $password = Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($this->password, $this->password_hash);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сравнить В yii2 есть валидатор для сравнения значений. Добавьте в модель правило:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            ['new_passwordRepeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'new_password'],
        ];
    }
```

И если все правила не дали ошибок, устанавливайте новый пароль

```
    if ($this->validatePassword($this->current_password)) {
        $this->setPassword($this->new_password);
        $this->save();
    }
```

Но лучше для всего этого создать отдельную модель. Тут пример формы:
 https://github.com/ElisDN/seokeys/blob/master/modules/user/forms/frontend/PasswordChangeForm.php